# How do I remove extra blank space in print statements?

Tags: python

The code I'm running works, but I've got tons of extra spaces where I shouldn't. My issue doesn't lie with the code itself, but the print statements.

```
current_price = int(input())
last_months_price = int(input())
change = current_price - last_months_price
mortgage = (current_price * 0.051) / 12

print('This house is $' , end=' ')
print(current_price , '.' , end=' ')
print('The change is $' , end=' ')
print(change , 'since last month.')
print('The estimated monthly mortgage is $' , end=' ')
print(f'{mortgage:.2f}' , '.')
```

This outputs:

```
This house is $ 200000 . The change is $ -10000 since last month.
The estimated monthly mortgage is $ 850.00 .
```

Comment: So, why are you adding all those extra spaces in the print statements? Also consider using f-strings as much as possible.

Comment: Maybe clearer as a multiline f-string with a single print statement i.e. `print(f'''This house is ${current_price}.
The change is ${change} since last month.
The estimated monthly mortgage is ${mortgage:.2f}''')`

Answer (score 1):

do your prints like this with f strings:

```
print(f'This house is ${current_price}. The change is ${change} since last month.')
print(f'The estimated monthly mortgage is ${mortgage:.2f}')
```